# In a cocoa application, 0x7FFF... appears to be an object on the stack, 0x000001... appears to be an object on the heap, but what is 0x618...?

Tags: cocoa, memory

I see these addresses all the time in my Cocoa application, 
`0x618....`

As far as I know, objects are allocated on either the stack or heap

As the application executes, stack frames are produced and placed on the stack, and any local pointers created in the scope of the stack are allocated on the stack (`0x7FFF...`)

And the actual underlying object that the pointer is referencing, is created on the heap (`0x0000010...`)

But it actually looks like this `0x618....` area in memory is also used as a heap for objects?  Because if you dereference a pointer to an `NSObject` subclass in the stack, I have seen it pretty much always point to `0x618...`

Are there two heaps for a Cocoa application?

Or is `0x618...` the actual heap for the application, and `0x000001` is just some other area of memory used for something else entirely?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The heap is typically below your stack and *above* your code. It is therefore impossible to be definitive where heap address may start, but your `0x618...` would not be unreasonable for a heap address.

Not all objects are on the heap, for example string constants are compiled into your code, and your `0x000001...` could easily be one.

There is also the complication of *tagged pointers*. Some objects are not even heap allocated but their value is combined with some tag bits into a tagged pointer, which isn't a pointer at all but will be found in variables of pointer type. `NSNumber` is like this for certain values, e.g. `@42` returns the "pointer" `0x2a37`.

HTH

Comment: so when you say compiled to code, and `0x000001` do you mean to say that the instructions compiled from the code is stored at the lowest addresses, and that's what the OS looks at to see which instructions to execute?

Comment: The code and data of an executable is loaded towards the low end of memory. The entry point of the application is defined in the executable file, the OS uses this to start the execution.